# Create new customer using CLI like admin

Tags: cli

There is the way to create admin user using `CLI` `php bin/magento admin:user:create`. Is there the same way to create the `new customer` for `front-end` access ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you cant create a new Customer like Admin user using CLI command in Magento 2.

You can create a custom module in Magento to create your own CLI command to create a new Customer.

Example:

Create a di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customer_user_create" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Console\Command\CustomerUserCreateCommand</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Create a file app/code/Vendor/Module/Console/Command/CustomerUserCreateCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Customer;

class CustomerUserCreateCommand extends Command
{
    protected $customerHelper;

    public function __construct(Customer $customerHelper)
    {
        $this->customerHelper = $customerHelper;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('customer:user:create')
            ->setDescription('Create new customer')
            ->setDefinition($this->getOptionsList());
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('<info>Creating new user...</info>');
        $this->customerHelper->setData($input);
        $this->customerHelper->execute();

        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<info>User created with the following data:</info>');
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer ID: ' . $this->customerHelper->getCustomerId());
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Website ID ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_WEBSITE));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer First Name: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_FIRSTNAME));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Last Name: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_LASTNAME));
        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Email: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_EMAIL));
        $output->writeln('<comment>Customer Password: ' . $input->getOption(Customer::KEY_PASSWORD));
    }

    protected function getOptionsList()
    {
        return [
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_FIRSTNAME, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer first name'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_LASTNAME, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer last name'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_EMAIL, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer email'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_PASSWORD, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Customer password'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_WEBSITE, null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, '(Required) Website ID'),
            new InputOption(Customer::KEY_SENDEMAIL, 0, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, '(1/0) Send email? (default 0)')
        ];
    }
}
```

Now create a helper file:
app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Customer.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\State;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const KEY_EMAIL = 'customer-email';
    const KEY_FIRSTNAME = 'customer-firstname';
    const KEY_LASTNAME = 'customer-lastname';
    const KEY_PASSWORD = 'customer-password';
    const KEY_WEBSITE = 'website';
    const KEY_SENDEMAIL = 'send-email';

    protected $storeManager;
    protected $state;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $data;
    protected $customerId;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        State $state,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function setData(Input $input)
    {
        $this->data = $input;
        return $this;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->state->setAreaCode('frontend');

        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer
            ->setWebsiteId($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_WEBSITE))
            ->setEmail($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_EMAIL))
            ->setFirstname($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_FIRSTNAME))
            ->setLastname($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_LASTNAME))
            ->setPassword($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_PASSWORD));
        $customer->save();

        $this->customerId = $customer->getId();

        if($this->data->getOption(self::KEY_SENDEMAIL)) {
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        }        
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return (int)$this->customerId;
    }
}
```

Now run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

On running php bin/magento you will find **customer:user:create** CLI command.

Example:

> php bin/magento customer:user:create --customer-firstname="John"
> --customer-lastname="Doe" --customer-email="john@example.com" --customer-password="john123" --website="1"

Please check for more reference here - https://techurbane.com/how-to-create-new-customers-using-cli-in-magento-2/

Comment: Excellent reply.  I built on your answer and added some additional validation and error handling and submitted it to packagist for ease of installation https://github.com/DominicWatts/CliCreateCustomer but otherwise this is a perfect answer

Comment: Thanks @DominicXigen, it will help other Developers as well in easy way. Happy Coding!

Comment: @DominicXigen Thanks for sharing the package. I see youhavefoundouthowtotypewithoutspaces.)) hard-readable, isn't it?)

Comment: @Kirby notveryhard

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with [magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2):

```
$ php n98-magerun2.phar customer:create [email] [password] [firstname] [lastname] [website]
```