# magento2 add address to customer via cli

Tags: magento2, php, cli

Using [Create new customer using CLI like admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293790/create-new-customer-using-cli-like-admin) approved method as a base I have been pulling my hair out on how to extend it so I can also add an address to the created user via CLI. any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of time.
customer.php

```
class Customer extends AbstractHelper
{
    const KEY_EMAIL = 'customer-email';
    const KEY_FIRSTNAME = 'customer-firstname';
    const KEY_LASTNAME = 'customer-lastname';
    const KEY_PASSWORD = 'customer-password';
    const KEY_WEBSITE = 'website';
    const KEY_SENDEMAIL = 'send-email';
    const KEY_CITY = 'city';
    const KEY_TELEPHONE = 'telephone';
    const KEY_STREET = 'street';
    const KEY_POSTCODE = 'postcode';
    const KEY_REGION = 'region';

_construct

        EmailNotificationInterface $emailNotificationInterface,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $dataAddressFactory,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer

        $this->dataAddressFactory = $dataAddressFactory;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->customer = $customer;

createcustomer()
        $city = $this->data->getOption(self::KEY_CITY);
        $telephone = $this->data->getOption(self::KEY_TELEPHONE);
        $street = $this->data->getOption(self::KEY_STREET);
        $postcode = $this->data->getOption(self::KEY_POSTCODE);
        $region = $this->data->getOption(self::KEY_REGION);

    public function saveAddress($customerId, $firstname, $lastname, $street_1, $city, $postcode, $telephone, $region)
    {
        try {
            $address = $this->dataAddressFactory->create();
            $address->setFirstname($firstname)
            ->setLastname($lastname);
            $address->setTelephone($telephone);
            $street[] = $street_1;
            $address->setStreet($street);

            $regionData = $this->getRegionCode($region);
            $address->setCity($city);
            $address->setCountryId($regionData['country_id']);
            $address->setPostcode($postcode);
            $address->setRegionId($regionData['region_id']);
            $address->setIsDefaultShipping(1);
            $address->setIsDefaultBilling(1);
            $address->setCustomerId($customerId);
            $this->addressRepository->save($address);
            $this->exception = false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->exception = $e;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

basically details what is required. Hope this helps someone else out.